API request fails with 500 error and loops infinitely
I have an Angular application with the following features:

A login method that retrieves an access token.
A getRefreshToken method that retrieves a refresh token.
A JwtInterceptor that:

Adds the token to the requests.
If a tokenInvalid error occurs, triggers another interceptor to call the getRefreshToken method.



Problem:
When the API is not running, the application continuously tries to call the getRefreshToken method in a loop to obtain a new refresh token, and I don’t understand why.
AuthenticationInfrastructure :
 private auth$: Observable<AuthenticationToken> | null | undefined;

  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<AuthenticationToken> {
    if (!this.auth$) {
      const body = new HttpParams()
        .set('username', email)
        .set('password', password);

      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      });

      this.auth$ = this.httpClient
        .post<AuthenticationToken>(
          'http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token/',
          body.toString(),
          { headers }
        )
        .pipe(shareReplay(1));
    }
    return this.auth$;
  }

  refreshToken() {
    return from(this.storage.get('refresh_token')).pipe(
      switchMap((storedRefreshToken) => {
        const body = new HttpParams()
          .set('grant_type', 'refresh_token')
          .set('refresh_token', storedRefreshToken);

        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set(
          'Content-Type',
          'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        );

        return this.httpClient
          .post<AuthenticationToken>(
            'http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token/',
            body,
            { headers }
          )
          .pipe(shareReplay(1));
      })
    );
  }

JwtInterceptor :
export function jwtInterceptor(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandlerFn) {
  const storage = inject(Storage);

  return from(storage.get('access_token')).pipe(
    switchMap((token) => {
      const newRequest = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        },
      });
      return next(newRequest);
    })
  );
}

export const refreshInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  const authInfra = inject(AuthenticationInfrastructure);
  const localStorage = inject(LocalStorageAuthenticationInfrastructure);
  const authApp = inject(AuthenticationApplication);

  return next(req).pipe(
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 0) {
        return authInfra.refreshToken().pipe(
          switchMap((tokenResponse: WithToken) => {
            localStorage.startSession({
              access_token: tokenResponse.access_token,
              refresh_token: tokenResponse.refresh_token,
            });
            const newAuthReq = req.clone({
              headers: req.headers.set(
                'Authorization',
                `Bearer ${tokenResponse.access_token}`
              ),
            });
            return next(newAuthReq);
          }),
          catchError((refreshError) => {
            console.error('Error refreshing token', refreshError);
            authApp.logout();
            return throwError(() => new Error('Token refresh failed!'));
          })
        );
      } else {
        return throwError(() => error);
      }
    })
  );
};

My Browser Consol :
user.application.ts:12 
 POST http://localhost:8080/master/clovis/protocol/openid-connect/token/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
user.application.ts:12 
 POST http://localhost:8080/master/clovis/protocol/openid-connect/token/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
user.application.ts:12 
 POST http://localhost:8080/master/clovis/protocol/openid-connect/token/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
user.application.ts:12 
 POST http://localhost:8080/master/clovis/protocol/openid-connect/token/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
user.application.ts:12 
 POST http://localhost:8080/master/clovis/protocol/openid-connect/token/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
user.application.ts:12 
 POST http://localhost:8080/master/clovis/protocol/openid-connect/token/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

